# Generic way to get the values from multiple controls

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a `Form` with multiple different controls like `ComboBox`, `TextBox` and `CheckBox`. I am looking for a generic way to get values from these controls while looping over them.

For example, something like this:

```
foreach(Control control in controls)
{
    values.Add(control.Value);
}
```

Is it possible or do I need to treat each `control` separately?

Comment: Are you getting a common property such as `Text`?

Comment: You can but using the `.Text` property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.control.text

Comment: Oh, right, didn't find it earlier on MSDN for some reason. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Panel myPanel = this.Panel1;

List<string> values = new List<string>();

foreach (Control control in myPanel.Controls)
{
    values.Add(control.Text);
}
```

But make sure you get only the controls you want. You can check the type just like

```
if(control is ComboBox)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Text solution is OK if every Control is a TextBox, but if you have some Label you'll end up with the text of the labels among the values, unless you fill your code with if's. A better solution could be to define a set of delegates that for each kind of Control return what is considered the value (e.g. Text for the TextBox and Checked for the CheckBox), put them in a dictionary, and use them to get the value for each control. The code could be something like this:

```
    public delegate object GetControlValue(Control aCtrl);

    private static Dictionary<Type, GetControlValue> _valDelegates;

    public static Dictionary<Type, GetControlValue> ValDelegates
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (_valDelegates == null)
                InitializeValDelegates();
            return _valDelegates; 
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeValDelegates()
    {
        _valDelegates = new Dictionary<Type, GetControlValue>();
        _valDelegates[typeof(TextBox)] = new GetControlValue(delegate(Control aCtrl) 
        {
            return ((TextBox)aCtrl).Text;
        });
        _valDelegates[typeof(CheckBox)] = new GetControlValue(delegate(Control aCtrl)
        {
            return ((CheckBox)aCtrl).Checked;
        });
        // ... other controls
    }

    public static object GetValue(Control aCtrl)
    {
        GetControlValue aDel;
        if (ValDelegates.TryGetValue(aCtrl.GetType(), out aDel))
            return aDel(aCtrl);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Then you can write:

```
        foreach (Control aCtrl in Controls)
        {
            object aVal = GetValue(aCtrl);
            if (aVal != null)
                values.Add(aVal);
        }
```